# IOS webview in full screen

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

This is properly a very simple question, but I'm completly new to IOS dev and Swift.

I'm trying to add a webview and make it fill the entire screen.

This is my code

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myWebView:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))

        self.view.addSubview(myWebView)
        let url = URL (string: "https://google.com");
        let request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL);
        myWebView.loadRequest(request);
        }
```

When I run the app only a white screen appear. I can load html as a string (loadHTMLString)

So 2 questions

- How do I get the web view to get fullscreen size?
- Why can't I load a url - I only get the white screen

Comment: you can use self.view.frame.size.width for width and self.view.frame.size.height for height

Comment: You haven't add webView to view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try This.**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , UIWebViewDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let myWebView:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
        myWebView.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(myWebView)
        let url = URL (string: "https://google.com");
        let request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL);
        myWebView.loadRequest(request);


    }

    func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        print("web view start loading")
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        print("web view load completely")
    }

    func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error) {
        print("web view loading fail : ",error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: @Birger check update its working fine for me i checked.

Comment: @Birger - add the delegate and check on which delegate will call

Comment: It works.. the phone had lost the wifi for some reason.. Thanks for the quick help

Comment: @DixitAkabari - where is the fail delegate

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code nothing is wrong in it.

Except the frame

The change you require -

```
  let myWebView:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
```

Check your internet connection if you are not able to load from url

```
webView:didFailLoadWithError
```

implement this function to check any future errors you get

Comment: The stupid phone had lost the wifi.. It loads the url now.. What a rookie mistake

Answer (score 0):

It's happen Because you haven't added `myWebView` to `view`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let myWebView:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))

    self.view.addSubview(myWebView)
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://google.com")!)
    myWebView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hear is your answers of two questions

**1.How do I get the web view to get fullscreen size?**

**Ans**: let myWebView:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height))

**2 Why can't I load a url - I only get the white screen**
**Ans**:
        let myWebView:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height))
        let url = URL (string: "https://google.com");
        let request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL);
        myWebView.loadRequest(request)
        self.view.addSubview(myWebView)

Load request before adding to self.view like above code
```

Answer (score 0):

> Change your webview size acooridng to your content after finishing your webview loading

```
 //MARK: - WebView Delegate Method
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    var frame = self.webView.frame
    frame.size.height = 1
    self.webView.frame = frame
    let fittingSize = self.webView.sizeThatFits(CGSize.zero)
    frame.size = fittingSize
    self.webView.needsUpdateConstraints()
    self.webView.frame.size.height = fittingSize.height
    self.webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have initilized myWebView with fixed height and width i.e 300.Try

```
let frame = self.view.frame
let width = frame.width
let height = frame.height
let myWebView:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
```

Using storyboard you can drag and drop webView in viewController and give constraints to your view (top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0) so that your web view will appear full screen. Now extend outlet of webView to the viewController and in viewDidLoad.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view
    let url = URL (string: "https://www.simplifiedios.net")
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL: url!)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Comment: is not a answer related to the ?, use myWebView.frame = self.view.bounds and als check transport security is added or not in your .plist